# Direct port manipulation takes 300 nanoseconds to execute for some reason

Tags: arduino-uno

I have this code

```
#include <Arduino.h>




void setup() {
  
  DDRD  = B00001000;

}
void delayNanoSeconds(int time){
    int ans = (float)time / 62.5;
    for(int i = 0; i < ans; i++){
        _NOP();


    }


}
#define delay250 _NOP(); _NOP();_NOP(); _NOP();
#define delay1000 delay250 delay250 delay250 delay250
void loop() {
  while(1){
       PORTD ^= B00001000;
       delay1000; delay1000;
  }                
 
  }
```

but I am getting delay of 2300 us
here is a picture of the logic analyzer [image]
and when I change delay to 250 or 1000 I am still getting this extra 300ns so why

Answer (score 6):

Remember: every single thing the CPU does takes time. Here is a
disassembly of your `loop()`:

```lisp
    ldi  r25, 0b00001000 ; r25 = B00001000
1:  in   r24, PORTD      ; r24 = PORTD
    eor  r24, r25        ; r24 ^= r25
    out  PORTD, r24      ; PORTD = r24
    nop
    nop
    ...
    nop
    rjmp 1b              ; goto previous label 1
```

As you see, besides your series of `nop`, there are four instructions in
the loop:

- `in`, `eor` and `out` take one cycle each
- `rjmp` takes two cycles.

That is a total overhead of 5 CPU cycles, or 312.5 ns when
running at 16 MHz. Pretty close to what you are seeing.

If you want an exact timings, you will have to disassemble your code and
count the overhead cycles, as I did here. Then, I suggest this simpler
approach:

```cpp
#define OVERHEAD_CYCLES 5

void loop() {
    for (;;) {
        PORTD ^= _BV(PD3);
        _delay_us(2 - OVERHEAD_CYCLES / (F_CPU / 1e6));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks for help

Comment: By the way how did you see the assymbly code

Comment: @Abdrlrahman: Re “how did you see the assymbly code”: `avr-objdump -SCz sketch.elf > sketch.lss`. You should see the location of the ELF file if you enable verbose compilation. The avr-objdump tool is somewhere in your Arduino installation, but the exact location may depend on your OS and the installed version of Arduino. You may have to search for it.

Comment: By the way shouldnt it be ``` _delay_us(2 - OVERHEAD_CYCLES  * (F_CPU / 1e6)); ``` instead of /

Comment: @Abdrlrahman: No, it's really a division. It ends up being 2 − 5/16.0 = 1.6875 µs.

Comment: `2 - OVERHEAD_CYCLES / (F_CPU / 1e6)` must be evaluated at compile time, of course. Thus the 2 cannot be added at runtime. Interesting that _delay_us has a float parameter, compared to the Arduino `delayMicroseconds(unsigned int)`